# How can I use a string from a text box as a reference for a range in excel vba?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm quite a newbie to VBA macros.  I created a Userform to save some time with copy and pasting Excel content.

Now I have the following issue: I get a string output from a Userform - Textbox (txtHRS_ANW). I created exactly the same names as named ranges. Now I want to use the string output as a reference for the named range. I am not able to add the double quotes in the brackets - I tried using """" and chr(34).

My code is as follows:

```
Private Sub cmdHRSLoading_Click()
Dim NameRange As String
If chkANW = True Then
    NameRange = Me.txtHRS_ANW.Value 'gives me following string HRS_ANW_CORP01 (until CORP10 depending on user entry)
    Sheet5.Range(NameRange).Select 'here I would like to use the string as a reference for the range
    Selection.Copy
    Sheet9.Range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Select
    Selection.Paste
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: do you get any error? what is its number? try to activate your sheet first with `Sheet5.activate` and next call `.select` line. Please remember that you don't need to select to trigger `.copy >> .paste` methods

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following procedure:

```
Private Sub cmdHRSLoading_Click()
Dim MyNameRange As String
        If chkANW = True Then
            MyNameRange = Me.txtHRS_ANW 'gives me following string HRS_ANW_CORP01 (until CORP10 depending on user entry)
            Application.Goto (MyNameRange) 'here I would like to use the string as a reference for the range
            Selection.Copy
            Sheet9.Activate
            Range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Select
            ActiveSheet.Paste
        End If
End Sub
```

Use `Application.GoTo` method. Also you do not need to use `.value` after `Me.txtHRS_ANW`

--- Use `ActiveSheet.Paste` not `Selection.Paste`

Comment: Hello Harun - Thanks for the fast and accurate answer! You saved my day - Spot on!

Comment: It might be worth explaining *why* you don't need to use `.Value` for other people that come to view this post in the future, and possibly the OP.

Answer (score 1):

Can also be written as:

```
Private Sub cmdHRSLoading_Click()

    If chkANW Then
        With Sheet9
            With .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 1)
                .Resize(Range(Me.txtHRS_ANW.Text).Rows.Count, Range(Me.txtHRS_ANW.Text).Columns.Count).Value = Range(Me.txtHRS_ANW.Text).Value
            End With
        End With
    End If

End Sub
```

Negating the need to use the clipboard.

Comment: Thank you! Just one more question - I wrote the macro in Excel 2016 - How can I make it work in Excel 2010?

Comment: There should be no difference in the code really - I'd suggest posting a new question of something isn't working on a specific version